# Increment all fields of a MongoDB document from c#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have this c# object:

```
public class Stats
{
      [BsonElement("Miss")]
      public uint Miss { get; set; }

      [BsonElement("Success")]
      public uint Success { get; set; }

      [BsonElement("Failed")]
      public uint Failed { get; set; }
}
```

and the mongodb doc

```
{
      "_id": {
            "$oid": "63c5f18ea66843e308557658"
      },
      "PlayerId": 10000,
      "Miss": 10,
      "Success": 20,
      "Failed": 5
}
```

For now to incremnt all I use this:

```
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("PlayerId", playerId);
var update = new BsonDocument("$inc", new BsonDocument {
      { "Miss", Stats.Miss },
      { "Success", Stats.Success },
      { "Failed", Stats.Failed }
  });
var doc = Collection.FindOneAndUpdateAsync(filter, update).Result;
```

Is there any other way simplified, as the actual doc has many more fields ?

Mention: PlayerId field to be excluded. I can also move it to _id if it is easier. All the remaining fields are int.

Thank you.

Comment: Using reflection? It is still unclear with your requirement. How many fields in your BSON document require to increment? Is there any field to be excluded? Is there any field which is not a number type?

Comment: hey, I updated my question. As for your question, all fields should be incremented. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have constructed the class just for the properties to be updated, you could use `.ToBsonDocument()` to convert an object to `BsonDocument` which is simpler than working with *System.Reflection*.

```cs
BsonDocument updateFields = stats.ToBsonDocument();

var update = new BsonDocument("$inc", updateFields);
```

> Demo

[image]